# Array variable is being removed from session in PHP

Tags: php, session

I'm storing the value of my multiselect combo in session.

```
<select id="abc" name="abc[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="select">Select</option>
<option value="first">first</option>
<option value="second">second</option>
<option value="third">third</option>
<option value="fourth">fourth</option>
</select>

$_SESSION['abc']=$_POST['abc'];
```

I'm getting the correct value of the session variable in the same file, but I have a 3-step signup process so in the 3rd step I'm getting all other variables except this value of the multiselect combo.

Also I'm not getting the value of one checkgroup (again because it is an array variable).

Do any one have any ideas about this?

Comment: Have you started the session in desired files?

Comment: yes man, n functionality was working fine before few hours, now suddenly getting issues

Comment: Whatever you posted is working fine in my side also. May be as Mathieu said it is the possibility of overwrite the $_SESSION['var'] with empty data.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably something else. Could you be forgetting to start your session again? Could it be possible that you overwrite the $_SESSION['var'] with empty data.

You should never have issues storing objects or arrays in sessions. The only problem you can have with storing data into a session is if you store RESOURCES.

Comment: sorry bt i'm not getting your answer, wht you mean by RESOURCES? and if i forgot to start the session than why i'm getting correct value of all other fields?

Comment: Agreed, I deleted my answer as I was confused with cookies.

Comment: Resources are objects in memory created by various functions, for example, the connections to mysql using mysqli or mysql functions generate a LINK RESOURCE, these cannot be stored into session variables because the real memory data in the extension is discarded at the end of the php page.

Comment: have removed all other code from my 3rd file, the value was there  till 3rd step of my signup, but when submit 3rd it gets removed, again i've removed all code from my 3rd step file